# Adding characters in string MsAccess 2000

Tags: ms-access-2003, ms-access-2000

I have table with one field:

```
Postal
48016350
48016350
48016350
48016350
48016350
```

I need to add "0" before each record and add "-"(dash) after 5th character in my MsAccess 2000 database.

My goal is:

```
Postal
04801-6350
04801-6350
04801-6350
04801-6350
04801-6350
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an update query:

```
UPDATE table
SET postal = "0" & Left(postal,4) & "-" & Right(postal,4)
```

You can paste the SQL into SQL View of the Query Design window. Make sure you make a copy of the table first.